# "Filtering" DataTable by Column NOT Rows

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

Given a DataTable with Columns A, B, C, D

looking for a clean way to restrict columns to say A, C 
similar to how the DataView restricts the Rows in a DataView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, posting it here for others who might land here

DataView.ToTable() method described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx

used as

DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable( flag, );

Answer (score 0):

Typically a `DataTable` has a relatively small, fixed number of named columns, and a potentially large, variable number of unnamed rows.  Hence filtering makes sense for rows, but not for columns.

Most applications would simply ignore the columns they are not interested in.

I don't think there's any way to do what you want, short of cloning the `DataTable` and deleting the columns you don't want.

Or perhaps pivoting the DataTable so that columns become rows.

Comment: it's usually easy to ignore the columns but we have a few use cases which work on the DataView where it would be nice to create a ColumnView combined with a DataView ! just a thought !